# ¿Cómo rotar la pantalla de vertical a horizontal y viceversa?

Tags: android

Mi problema es que trato de poder invertir la pantalla o el layout de vertical, porque yo lo defino como vertical y luego quiero pasarlo a horizontal, sin que actualice o haga que vuelva a cargar la activity.

Mi código:

Este código `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` lo uso para definir en el `onCreate()` que la orientación debe ser vertical y también declaro esta variable `boolean orienta;` cuyo valor es verdadero

Y con este método determino si la pantalla esta en vertical y luego la pasa a horizontal o viceversa

```
    private void oree(){

        if(orienta){
            this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            orienta=false;
        }else{
            this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            orienta=true;
        }


}
```

Pero lo único que hace es actualizar la actividad y no la rota.

Si conocen algo referente a este tema, estaré encantado de escucharle. Gracias.

Comment: No se entiende bien. ¿Quieres forzar a que cuando se crea la Activity la pantalla esté en vertical o quieres simplemente que le sea permitido a tu App que el usuario rote la pantalla como a él le plazca? [Este apartado de la Documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) trata de cosas importantes sobre tu pregunta, y está en castellano.

Comment: No mi punto es rotar la pantalla desde mi aplicación, no que el usuario lo haga.Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres es cambiar de una orientación a otra, considero que lo recomendable es definir a tu Activity una orientación en lugar de estar cambiando a un estado deseado.

Puedes definirla como **vertical** (portrait):

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

programaticamente :

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

o como **horizontal** (landscape):

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

programáticamente :

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

---

> Mi problema es que trato de poder invertir la pantalla o el layout de
>   vertical, porque yo lo defino como vertical y luego quiero pasarlo a
>   horizontal, sin que actualice o haga que vuelva a cargar la activity.

**Si deseas que no se cree nuevamente la `Activity`**, puedes definir la propiedad `android:configChanges` con este valor:

```
 <activity android:name=".Activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

con esto evitarás que la `Activity` vuelva a crearse al rotar, notaras que no entrara nuevamente a llamar el método `onCreate()`.

Comment: Ok gracias, pero mi punto trata de poder modificar la orientación programaticamente en cualquier momento.

Comment: @Abraham.P El punto es que los usuarios de tu app es gente democrática y no les va a gustar que seas tú el que les des la orientación de su pantalla. Vas a tener problemas con los usuarios por eso, ya lo verás :)  Si de todos modos insistes, lee lo que dice Android en el enlace que te puse en un comentario, más arriba, en la propia pregunta. Por lo demás, en esta respuesta se te indica la forma de proceder.

Comment: No amigo mi aplicación les brinda la forma de orientarla en la forma que ellos quieran, pero de una manera controlada desde mi aplicación y el fragmento de código que ha ofrecido me ha ayudado. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Otra manera para tratar la rotación es permitir la creación de la actividad y con el flag `savedInstanceState` puedes determinar si es la primera vez que se crea o bien ya se ha creado.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   //primera vez, resetear interfaz
} else {
   //posteriores, aquí para actualizar los datos como estaban
}
```

Previamente los datos se debe guardar en `onSaveInstanceState` ejemplo

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean("MY_BUNDLE", isChecked);
    super.onViewStateRestored(outState);
}
```

Para recuperar el valor

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    isChecked = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MY_BUNDLE", false);
    cbCheckBox.setChecked(isChecked);
}
```

Las propiedades con `static` se mantienen en memoria al rotar el dispositivo.

Comment: Gracias por su aporte.